# Import with generic code flat file into sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm a dummy in Python; I would like to import data into SQLite db. For example, I'll have many tables to upload, and I need to do a generic code to be able to upload all my database. have

My script follow the story telling:

1. Step 1 configuration, for each table (SAP tables codification required) the path of the file (for now, my file are txt).
2. Step 2 create tables concerned into the SQLite db
3. Step 3 read the different files and upload data into my db.

Step 1 and 2 are working well
Step 3 I can't find the process.

This is my code:

```
import os
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
import configparser
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys, codecs

#parameters
now = datetime.today()
fnow = now.strftime('%Y%m%d')
hnow = now.strftime('%H:%M')

#database
sqlite_file = 'data.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
# Create Data table if not exists
# T030
# T156X
# T156W

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T030
             (KTOPL text(4) not null,KTOSL text(4) not null, BWMOD text(4), KOMOK text(3), 
             BKLAS text(4), KONTS text(10), KONTH text(10))''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T156X
             (BWART text(4) not null, WERTU text(1), MENGU text(1), SOBKZ text(1), KZBEW text(1), KZVBR text(1),
              BUSTW text(4), OIHACCDTN text(2), CNT02 integer(3), KOMOK text(3), XPKON text(1))''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T156W
             (BUSTW text(4) not null, CNT02 integer(3) not null, VORSL text(4), FELDN text(16), SHNAM text(16), SMNAM text(16), 
             XBMAT text(1), XBBST text(1), XBFAU text(1), XAUTO text(1), XPANZ text(1), XBSIM text(1), BUZID text(1),
              XUMBW text(1), XKAAO text(1), XMFRW text(1), X2DOC text(1), XBGBB text(1), SETTLEMENT text(1), OIPOSTZERO text(1))''')
# Create Users table if not exists
conn.commit()

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['Tables'] = {}
config['Tables']['T030']=''
config['Tables']['T156X']=''
config['Tables']['T156W']=''

# create config file
if not os.path.isfile('config.ini'):
    with open('config.ini','w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)


def config_maj():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    for key in config['Tables']:
        print(key)
        fichier = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r',)
        fichier = str(fichier.name)
        config['Tables'][str(key)] = fichier
    with open('config.ini','w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)


def upload_table():
    # lire le fichier
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    for key in config['Tables']:
        Table = config['Tables'][key]
#        with open(Table, 'r') as u_table:
    # Tester si la table est vide, si non on vide la table
        if nb_entry(key) != 0:
            print(nb_entry(key))
            purge_table(key)
        load_table(key, Table)


def nb_entry(table):
    table_name = table.upper()
    query = f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {table_name}"
    c.execute(query)
    result = c.fetchone()
    return result[0]
    
    
def purge_table(table):
    sql = f"DELETE FROM  {table.upper()}"
    c.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()

def load_table(table,chemin):
    t_table =[]
    with open(chemin, 'r', encoding='utf-16') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
    for line in contents:
        dr = line.strip().split("\t")
        if len(dr) > 1:
            for i in range(len(dr)):
                if len(t_table) == 0:
                    t_table = dr
                else:
                    sql_com = [(i[])]

    print(t_table)
    pass


test = upload_table()
```

I can't find the solution in the function load_table(table,chemin).
Table is the name of my table
chemin is the path and name of my file.

Into the dr object, I have the contains of my entries.

In the next step I would like to do some think like
sql instruction= insert * from {dr} into {table} but it's not working.

Could you give me some tips to find a solution,

Thanks in advance,

Philippe

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: Open file, for each record read from the file, split it up into fields and insert into the appropriate table. Repeat for all desired files.

Comment: @Shawn, i try but can't find the good way.